# RecyclerView different itemDecoration for different items

Tags: android, margins, android-recyclerview

I am using the `RecyclerView` in my application and for the needs of my design, I need to have different margins between the items in my list (For example: the space between the first two items to be 16dp, the space between the second and the third item 32dp etc.). I read that you can add item decoration to the `RecyclerView` and create that space between the items. But this thing adds the same margin between all the items, and I want different behavior for different items. My questions is, can this be done using the item decoration? And how is this approach better than changing the margin of the item (view) in for example, the `onBindViewHolder` method in the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try overriding ItemDecoration.getItemOffsets?

Comment: yes, but how can I add different margin for different items? should I iterate the items somehow?

Comment: is it called once or several times?  if the latter see the params that are passed

Comment: It's called several times and the parameters are (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)..

Comment: so you have different View view in each call, right? so what is the problem actually?

Comment: Well, for my needs, I was going to make the decision of having one or another type of margin according to the item position and the data associated with that position. How can I do that with these parameters? The getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) is now deprecated..

Comment: use RecyclerView. getChildViewHolder then

Comment: Yes, it seems that that's what I need. I am sorry to have troubled you, but I am not used to using RecyclerView. Thx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can override [`RecyclerView.ItemDecoration#getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html#getItemOffsets(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.view.View,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State)), it is called for every visible child `View view`, you can get its position within the adapter by calling:

```
parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
```

or the view holder by calling:

```
parent.getChildViewHolder(view)
```